# What move is better in this position, Ke7 or g6?

Tags: opening, opening-traps

1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 f6 3.Nxe5 fxe5 4.Qh5 And in this position what move for black is better, Ke7 or g6 ? I know that such position will never occur in game between good players because after Nxe5, fxe5 is bad move because of the queen attack. But on one of YouTube chess channels in this position move g6 was said is better, but there wasn't explanation, is it so and why ?

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry, I meant g6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4...g6 is technically better, because it only loses a rook at once due to 5.Qxe5 Qe7 6.Qxh8, leaving White with a winning position, while after 4...Ke7 5.Qxe5 Kf7 6.Bc4+ Black will have to give even more material to postpone checkmate: 6...d5 7.Bxd5 Kg6 8.Bxb7 Bxb7 9.Qf5 Kh6 10.d4 g5 11.h4 +-

As said by the OP, 2...f6? and 3...fxe5? are the bad moves in this line.